# Obfuscating numbers in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a challenge that calls for obfuscating numbers in a string, such as a SSN, for example: `XXX-XX-4430`.  I've gotten pretty close:

```
def hide_all_ssns(string)
  string.scan(/\w{3}-\w{2}-\w{4}/)
  string.gsub('/\w{3}-\w{2}', 'XXX-XX')
end
```

but I get an error:

```
Error! hide_all_ssns obfuscates any SSNs in the string expected:
"XXX-XX-1422, XXX-XX-0744, XXX-XX-8762" got: "234-60-1422,
350-80-0744, 013-60-8762" (using ==)
```

I initially had the regular-expression `(/\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/)` but thought that the problem was attempting to convert the integers in the string to `X`. Now I'm using `\w`, yet I am getting the same error.

Does anyone have any insight?  I'm a newbie to coding and have exhausted Ruby-doc, as well as any blogs I can find on regex/`gsub`, but I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Are you trying to mutate `string`?  If so, set `string = string.gsub...` or using `string.gsub!`

Comment: I kind of doubt you've exhausted Ruby-doc along with all the blogs you could find on regex/gsub.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the answer.  Unfortunately as a newbie to coding it's pretty easy to spend hours digging and still not find an answer - appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're mis-using `gsub` (your regular expression needs to be between forward slashes), but I still thing `gsub!` is what you want...

```
def hide_all_ssns(string)
  string.scan(/\w{3}-\w{2}-\w{4}/)
  string.gsub!(/\w{3}-\w{2}/, 'XXX-XX')
end
```

Working example:

```
1.9.3p448 :063 > string = "123-45-6789"
 => "123-45-6789" 

1.9.3p448 :064 > def hide_all_ssns(string)
1.9.3p448 :065?>   string.scan(/\w{3}-\w{2}-\w{4}/)
1.9.3p448 :066?>   string.gsub!(/\w{3}-\w{2}/, 'XXX-XX')
1.9.3p448 :067?> end
 => nil 

1.9.3p448 :068 > hide_all_ssns(string)
 => "XXX-XX-6789" 

1.9.3p448 :069 > string
 => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Comment: So I figured it out after pinging a friend - I was missing the forward slash at the end and unnecessarily had the ' ' around the regex code.  Thank you so much for your answer and insight, so helpful to someone just starting out!

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be so hard? All U.S. social security numbers are the [same format](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/history/ssn/geocard.html), right? So, work from that point. Here's some variations on a theme, ordered by escalating obscurity:

```
ssn = '123-45-6789'   # => "123-45-6789"
ssn[0, 6] = 'XXX-XX'  # => "XXX-XX"
ssn                   # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Or:

```
numbers = ssn.scan(/\d+/)  # => ["123", "45", "6789"]
'XXX-XX-' + numbers.last   # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Or:

```
ssn = '123-45-6789'                    # => "123-45-6789"
ssn[0, 6] = ssn[0, 6].gsub(/\d/, 'X')  # => "XXX-XX"
ssn                                    # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Or:

```
ssn[0,6] = ssn[0, 6].tr('0-9', 'X')  # => "XXX-XX"
ssn                                  # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Or:

```
numbers = ssn.split('-')                                         # => ["123", "45", "6789"]
[*numbers[0, 2].map{ |s| 'X' * s.size }, numbers[-1]].join('-')  # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Or:

```
ssn[/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/]                                       # => "123-45-6789"
[$1, $2, $3]                                                   # => ["123", "45", "6789"]
[$3, *[$2, $1].map{ |s| s.gsub(/./, 'X') }].reverse.join('-')  # => "XXX-XX-6789"
```

Of course, using one of these would cheating, since you're supposed to figure the challenge out by yourself, but they're good food for thought and a decent starting point for your own solution.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man - I figured it out and am pretty pleased that I was able to do so without "cheating".  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple... You could maybe try something like this:

```
crypted = ('X' * 6) + "4543-2329-1354-1111".to_s[14..18]
=> "XXXXXX-1111"
```

Comment: Wow,thank you so much for your insight!  I got the code to work - I was missing a forward slash.  I will definitely refer to this as a way to refactor my code - you rock!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mala_sf no worries :)